# Is there any control that take System.Drawing.Image object and view as image?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, image

I return array of images ( System.Drawing.Image[] ) from database and i want to show them in datagrid or datalist .. Can any tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no control that does that as far as I know.

Basically what you need to do is add a new Page (or Handler) to your solution, and from that page, you do a `Response.BinaryWrite` to write the image directly to the response. Then in your main page, you link an image to that new page kind of like `<img src="MyImage.aspx?Id=1"/>`

These links should provide you a good start.

http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20210304133428/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx

Comment: i already use this way but i always ask if i have a gridView that will show 10 images in the page .. is mean u need to do 10 connections to the server to get each image :( ?

Comment: You are correct. That's why you should use a handler instead of a page (less resources needed) and url rewriting to serve the images on disk without even entering the ASP.Net pipe (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

If the images are fairly small, you could send them Base64 encoded with the markup of the web page.

**Please note**: This is only a demonstration in order to show that it is possible to do this, I don't think this should be done on a real web site.

In reality, you should:

- consider **writing those images to disk** and serving them as regular images and with proper caching headers without hitting the database each time.
- **implement a handler** which checks first if the image exists already on disk, and only retrieve it from the db if needed (which will only be the first time a image is asked for).
- use **url rewriting**, and only pass the image urls which do not correspond to a image on disk to the handler. This is faster than passing all request through the ASP.Net pipe. [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) does that perfectly well.

This said, here's the demonstration with base64 encoded images.
Add a Repeater to your page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ImageRepeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltImage" runat="server"><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{0}" alt="" /></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your codebehind, bind the images to the repeater:

```
private void BindImages(System.Drawing.Image[] images)
{
    this.ImageRepeater.DataSource = images;
    this.ImageRepeater.ItemDataBound += delegate(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = e.Item.DataItem as System.Drawing.Image;
            Literal lt = e.Item.FindControl("ltImage") as Literal;

            lt.Text = string.Format(lt.Text, ImageToBase64(img, ImageFormat.Jpeg));
        }
    };
    this.ImageRepeater.DataBind();
}

private string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image,  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{ 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}
```

You may want to disable Viewstate...

Thanks to [dailycoding.com](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx) and [Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/) for code bits.